# synchronizing two copies of a mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have a mongodb server running on an amazon ec2 VM. The VM has about 100GB storage, and the DB grows at a pace of about 3GB per day.

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to keep the DB on an external server, and only have the mongodb on the amazon VM maintain data for one or two days. The data should then be synched to the external server and deleted from the DB on the VM.

mongo has a clone method, but it doesn't look like it will do the job. Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't really do this easily (at least not yet). You're best off implementing this at the application layer for now, if you can.

If that's really not an option, you could try using sharding...

It's a bit tricky to accomplish this, but probably the easiest way to do it is to shard by date, and as each day passes, you both add and remove a shard from your VM mongo (for example, you might remove the shard for 3 days ago, and add a new shard for 1 day in the future). Then, use your external server as the primary shard, so that data is always migrated to that server when it does not fall within your 3 day rolling shard.

Take a look at [Administer and Manage Shard Tags](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/) for how to setup your shard tags such that they apply for each date. Each night, you'll need a cron job to remove and add these shards. One downside of this approach could be that you need to move 3 GB of data every night from VM to external server.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the sharding approach.